# Storing 3rd Party OAuth Credentials (React)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, oauth-2.0, environment-variables, google-oauth

I'm attempting to implement Google OAuth with the package [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login), but I found I had some questions after reading the docs:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <GoogleLogin
    clientId="658977310896-knrl3gka66fldh83dao2rhgbblmd4un9.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={responseGoogle}
    onFailure={responseGoogle}
  />,
  document.getElementById('googleButton')
);
```

In this example, provided in the usage instructions, the developer's clientId is hardcoded into the component. I'm fairly certain this should never happen, so I wanted to get some clarification as to what the best practice for storing 3rd party authentication credentials actually is.

(Not sure if this is relevant, but I wanted to add that I'll be using a rails backend. I believe I've seen an implementation in the past wherein a request is first made to the backend, where the actual oauth request is then dispatched using credentials that have been stored as environment variables in the server so that they never pass through the browser? If that makes sense?)

Any advice or clarification on this subject would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're talking about 2 different things. The lib that you are using is meant for client-side oauth... You could set up a `.env.` and keep your client id there but ultimately anything client side - there is no way to really hide (having said that, it's fine to use it...)

Comment: I'm with you that the library is client side and that the clientId therefore can't be protected. But that's also precisely my confusion. Why would this package exist if you can't protect your credentials? Am I wrong for thinking I need to in the first place?

Comment: Depends on your use case... Too broad to go into here...